# Why I cant access directly to array object in React Native [REDUX]

Tags: react-native, redux

I want to know Why I can't access directly to object in array from mapStateToProps but I can when I use map function.

// works

```
<View>
{this.props.m.map((item,index) => {
  return(
    <Text key={index}>
      This is my fixed footer! {item.title}
    </Text>
    )
})     
 }
</View>
```

// Doesn't work

```
 <Text>
 {this.props.m[0].title}
 </Text>
```

I get following error:
[image]

I use redux-thunk middleware to use async function and action creator. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

M isnt an array, its just an iterable object, thats why map works, and acessing m[0] doesnt, try  `array =  m.values()`, now array has all values from m, now you can do `array[0]`